# DSolve -> no results

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a system of differential equations.

```
eqn = {
y''[t] == (39/10000 + 
  58/10000/(1 + 
     Exp[(Sqrt[(Cos[10*2*Pi/360])^2 + y'[t]^2 + z'[t]^2] - 35)/
       5]))*Sqrt[(Cos[10*2*Pi/360])^2 + y'[t]^2 + z'[t]^2]*y'[t], 
z''[t] == (39/10000 + 
   58/10000/(1 + 
      Exp[(Sqrt[(Cos[10*2*Pi/360])^2 + y'[t]^2 + z'[t]^2] - 35)/
        5]))*Sqrt[(Cos[10*2*Pi/360])^2 + y'[t]^2 + z'[t]^2]*
 z'[t] + 41/100000 *(30*(Cos[10*2*Pi/360])), y'[0] == 0, 
z'[0] == 40*Sin[10*2*Pi/360], y[0] == 0, z[0] == 3/2}

sol = DSolve[eqn, {y[t], z[t]}, t]
```

However this does not give me any solution. Only oupout is my input. I cannot seem to figure out what I did wrong...

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried solving it with `NDSolve` ?

Comment: I have to get an analytical solution :/

Comment: I believe Sektor was hinting that an analytical solution to your non-linear ODE probably does not exist. Perhaps math.stackexchange.com could help you determine if one does.